# Scala - append RDD to itself

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
for (fordate <- 2 to 30) {
  val dataRDD = sc.textFile("s3n://mypath" + fordate + "/*")
  val a = 1
  val c = fordate - 1
  for (b <- a to c) {
    val cumilativeRDD1 = sc.textFile("s3n://mypath/" + b + "/*")
    val cumilativeRDD : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]  = sc.union(cumilativeRDD1, cumilativeRDD)
    if (b == c) {
      val incrementalDEviceIDs = dataRDD.subtract(cumilativeRDD)
      val countofIDs = incrementalDEviceIDs.distinct().count()
      println(s"201611 $fordate  $countofIDs")
    }
  }
}
```

i have a data set where i get deviceIDs on daily basis. i need to figure out the incremental count per day but when i join `cumilativeRDD` to itself it saysthrows following error:

> forward reference extends over definition of value cumilativeRDD

how can i overcome this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you describe the *intention* of this process?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the *intention* is to diff `day[x]` with the  `sum[1,x-1](day[i])`. Aside of solving the question of the variable scope, this implementation is n^2 on data coming from the network. You read `day 1` x `n`  times, `day 2` x `n-1` times, ... . I suggest you review your process to cummulate seen data and compare in one pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
val cumilativeRDD : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]  = sc.union(cumilativeRDD1 ,cumilativeRDD)
```

You're using `cumilativeRDD` before it's declaration. Variable assignment works from right to left. The right side of `=` defines the variable on the left. Therefore you cannot use the variable inside it's own definition. Because on the right side of the equation the variable does not yet exist.

You have to init `cumilativeRDD` in the first run and then you can you use it in following runs:

```
 var cumilativeRDD: Option[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]] = None
 for (fordate <- 2 to 30) {
    val DataRDD = sc.textFile("s3n://mypath" + fordate + "/*")
    val c = fordate - 1
    for (b <- 1 to c) {
      val cumilativeRDD1 = sc.textFile("s3n://mypath/" + b + "/*")
      if (cumilativeRDD.isEmpty) cumilativeRDD = Some(cumilativeRDD1)
      else cumilativeRDD = Some(sc.union(cumilativeRDD1, cumilativeRDD.get))

      if (b == c) {
        val IncrementalDEviceIDs = DataRDD.subtract(cumilativeRDD.get)
        val countofIDs = IncrementalDEviceIDs.distinct().count()
        println("201611" + fordate + "  " + countofIDs)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: even after doing this it throws the same error: `forward reference extends over definition of value`

Comment: Could you give some more context? On which line is this error thrown exactly?

Comment: _error: forward reference extends over definition of value cumilativeRDD_
               `val cumilativeRDD : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]  = sc.union(cumilativeRDD1 ,cumilativeRDD)`

Comment: But you no longer find this line in the code of my answer. If you run the code of my proposed solution do you get the error for this line: `else cumilativeRDD = Some(sc.union(cumilativeRDD1, cumilativeRDD.get))`?

Comment: This worked :) can you let me know how does this change effect

Comment: I updated my solution. I hope it explains it a bit better now.